# How to run cronjobs manually regardless of their timings for testing purposes

Tags: linux, command-line, cron

The following are in the crontab -e. Now I just want to run those cronjobs without their scheduled timings. How to run on the command line.

```
0 22 * * 4 /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/testExample/artisan  schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
0 22 * * 3 /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/testExample/artisan  schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Log in as whatever user owns the crontab, then just run the command line there? But take care to include/exclude any env var settings in the crontab file as required. Or, if you want to run the script it in the exact environment cron would run it in, add a new crontab rule that matches a single minute in the near future (and remember to remove the line within the next year)

Comment: I normally test my cron scripts by setting up a cron job that runs it at about my update frequency -- say every 10 or 15 minutes. I put a clock in front of me so I know when I am about to get a test -- `xclock -d &`. I have an `exit` command near the top of my script which I can uncomment if I'm not ready for a test. I save my edits a few seconds before the cron ticks. I wrap the job in a redirect to a file which I re-read in an editor after each run. That almost exactly emulates the rhythm of my usual edit-build-test cycle anyway.